# How to check 4 inputs and set flag in Microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, input

I have a PIC MCU and have 4 input pins. I need to check the status of inputs and set the value of flag. Like if input 1 is active, then value of flag should be 1, if input 1 and input 2 are activated then flag is 2. FOr input 1,2,3 flag=3. For this kind of logic, I though of using multiple if else condition:

```
if(input1==high)
{
  flag = 1;
  if(input2==high)
  {
    flag=2;
    if(input3==high)
    {
    flag=3;
    if(input4==high)
    {
      flag=4;
     }
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any way I can skip this if else and can use some other c logic. Please help.

Comment: It depends, can you read these 4 inputs at the same time (I mean one mcu operation)? Do they belong to the same port?

Comment: Yes they belong to same port and can be read at same time. These input can occur at the same time. Like 4inputs can be high at same time

Comment: Why do you want to skip the **if** logic part and use something else????

Comment: Because I thought there might a better option than using if

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Are you wanting the value of Flag to represent the **NUMBER** of bits that are high?  In other words, what is the value of Flag when only input 3 is high?\

Comment: 4 bits input means u have 2^4 combinations. Out of that ur only interested in conditions 1,3,7,15? Have u considered the other conditions?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using a pre-initialised table, like this:

```
static uint8 table[] = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 4 };

port_val = Read_Port() & 0xf;
flag = table[port_val];
```

I'm more of an AVR hacker myself, and don't know what the PIC equivalent would be of using PROGMEM to put the table in ROM.

And for 8 bits instead of 4:

```
uint8 port_val = Read_Port() & 0xff;
flag = table[port_val & 0xf];
if (flag == 4) flag += table[port_val >> 4];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that these 4 inputs are lower 4 bits of same port - Pin 0 to 3. You can change values if pins are different.

I would go with something like

```
port_val = Read_Port() & 0x0F;
switch(port_val)
{
  case 0x01: // Only input 1 is set
     flag = 1;
  break;

  case 0x03: // input 1 and 2 set
     flag = 2;
  break;

  case 0x07: // input 1,2 and 3 are set
     flag = 3;
   break;

  case 0x0F: //All 4 inputs are set
     flag = 4;
  break;
  default:
   //Optional
   flag = 0;
   break;
}
```

Comment: With input 5, the original program has input1 = 1 and input2 = 0 (and input3 = 1), so the result is flag = 1. Swanand's program gives flag = 0 in that case.  I'm not 100% sure this matters in the OP's situation, but the two programs do behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
flag =0 ;
port_val = Read_port() & 0x0F;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{
   if(port_val & (0x01<<i))
   {
     flag++;
   }
   else
   {
      break;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it as a loop, try this:

```
uint8 port_val = Read_Port() & 0xf;
flag = 0;
while (port_val & 1) {
    flag++; port_val = port_val >> 1;
}
```

But I would use the lookup table myself: it's faster and very probably smaller too.

Comment: I would vote against my own answer if I could.  Sadly, SE doesn't seem to appreciate the irony.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one concise line of C code as follows:

```
flag=x&1?x&2?x&4?x&8?4:3:2:1:0;   // set flag appropriately
```

It's very important to add comments as I did above to indicate precisely what the statement does. ;-)

Comment: Sorry if this is me going into teacher mode, but this program will translate into object code that's very similar to the OP's original program: the conditional expressions written with ? and : will generate jumping code just like the conditional statements written with if and else.  A nice alternative, though.

Comment: @MikeSpivey Of course, and when I compiled it for the AVR it took up exactly the same space. It might actually be worse than the original code for the PIC, I recall that the '?' operator was not very efficient- in fact the Hitech compiler won't handle nested ternary operators at all. Maybe (probably) XC8 works.

Comment: Ha!  My students could do better than that -- but we sensibly target the ARM and save ourselves a lot of grief.